# How can I select second nearest agent from the lorry?

Tags: anylogic, agent

I need to select the second nearest warehouse (yellow building) from the lorry in the pic. This choice have to made based on a condition (for example: stock units more than 0). Do you know any command to do it? Thank you.

[con](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcJsm.jpg)

Comment: Depnds on your model hierarchy. What agent populations are embedded where... Share those details and we can help. Also, this tutorial does something very similar and can also answer your question: https://anylogic.help/tutorials/gis/index.html